# Using "SELECT" command in MySQL to order by specific words?

Tags: mysql

Currently trying to use something such as

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, RaceLevel 
FROM Races, Riders 
ORDER BY FIELD("Easy","Intermediate","Advanced");
```

This returns a table that is not organized in this way.  How would I go about getting the table to organize itself in a way where Easy, Intermediate, and Advanced would be organized top-to-bottom?  Thanks for any help.

Also, how would I made a SELECT statement where it would separate each difficulty into different "tables" when using the select statement?  I'm not trying to create new tables, I just want to use the select statement to show the information together, and separately in a maximum of 4 full commands.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The field function takes the column you want to sort by as the first parameter.

So your query should be:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, RaceLevel
  FROM Races, Riders
  ORDER BY FIELD(RaceLevel, "Easy","Intermediate","Advanced");
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked, do you also know how I could use the select statement to only show the FirstName, LastName, and RaceLevel fields where RaceLevel would be equal to "easy"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. When posting questions it's best to limit each question to a specific problem and search for prior questions that may have your answer. It seems you may be new to sql  so I'd definitely suggest get comfortable with the documentation that can be found at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html . I know it's alot so let me highlight specifically for your second question you want to use a `where` clause
`SELECT FirstName, LastName, RaceLevel FROM Races, Riders Where RaceLevel = 'easy'`. Also please do accept answers for questions you ask if they suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, RaceLevel
FROM Races, Riders 
ORDER BY case when RaceLevel = "Easy" then 1
              when RaceLevel = "Intermediate" then 2
              else 3
         end case
```